If I get an error in powershell, what are the three dots "..."?
If I get an error with a powershell command, the output is trimmed with three dots.
The three dots "..." in PowerShell errors, indicating that there is more information available about the error, but it has been omitted from the displayed message for brevity. You can typically get the full error details by piping the error to a cmdlet like Format-List or Out-String.
However, I find that this doesn't get me the full output. Is there anything else I can do to get the full output?;)
$result = Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery -WorkspaceId $appId -Query $query
Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery : Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
At line:1 char:11
+ $result = Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery -WorkspaceId $appId -Quer ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery], ErrorResponseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.OperationalInsights.Query.InvokeOperationalInsightsQuery


This is because it normally doesn't show you the whole line of the source code that caused the error, only the relevant part and puts the ~'s under it. The details of the error are not truncated (CategoryInfo & FullyQualifiedErrorId).

It's a good question, but the title is somewhat misleading, given that your question body clearly shows that you do know that the ... indicates an abbreviated form of the original command.

See $error[0] | select * for more info:
dir foo3

dir : Cannot find path 'C:\users\admin\foo3' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ dir foo3
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\users\admin\foo3:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand


$error[0] | select *


writeErrorStream      : True
PSMessageDetails      :
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException: Cannot find path 'C:\users\admin\foo3'
                        because it does not exist.
                           at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.GetChildItems(String path, Boolean
                        recurse, UInt32 depth, CmdletProviderContext context)
                           at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand.ProcessRecord()
TargetObject          : C:\users\admin\foo3
CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\users\admin\foo3:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {0, 1}


More detailed, but if you put a long code, like $result = 'a very long string with unnecessarily many characters' + thisiscausingerror, you still get dots where it shows the relevant problematic portion.

It's in there somewhere... $error[0] | fc * -force | findstr /i thisiscausingerror


Use $Error[0].Invocation.Line or - more robustly, but only if you're running PowerShell (Core) 7 v7.4+ - $Error[0].Invocation.Statement to get the full line / statement (which may span multiple lines) that triggered the error.

$Error[0] is the most recent error that occurred in the session, stored in the automatic $Error variable.

Alternatively, when calling cmdlets or advanced functions / scripts, you can collect command-specific errors via the common -ErrorVariable parameter in a custom variable; e.g. Get-ChildItem NoSuch1, NoSuch2 -ErrorVariable errs collects the errors in self-chosen variable $errs, as a [System.Collections.ArrayList] instance. Add -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue to silence the immediate error output.


PowerShell errors are of type System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord, and their .Invocation property contains an instance of type System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo, which in turn has a .Line property and, in PowerShell 7.4+, also a .Statement property.


However, note that this typically won't tell you more than the error (exception) message stored in the error record (which you can access by simply calling .ToString() on it), given that you'll get the line as submitted, i.e. the source-code representation of the command, with any variable references / subexpressions unexpanded, i.e. you won't know the actual values passed.

A simple example (note that running interactively in PowerShell 7 prints a single-line representation without an (abbreviated) source-code line; run the code from a script file to see the latter):
# This reports an error about an unexpected positional argument,
# showing an abbreviated version of the line.
Get-ChildItem xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx $HOME $PSVersionTable

# Reports the full original line that triggered the most recent error.
# In PowerShell 7.4+, it's better to use 
#   $Error[0].InvocationInfo.Statement
# This will reproduce the command submitted above as-is, i.e. with 
# unexpanded variable references.
$Error[0].InvocationInfo.Line

